# Can't get xpath to locate element

Tags: xpath

I have this piece of HTML and I'm trying to select the `<a href>` link using xpath.

```
<li class="footable-page-nav" data-page="next" aria-label="next"><a class="footable-page-link xh-highlight" href="#">›</a></li>
```

I need the selector to be reasonably specific since "footable-page-link" exists in multiple places in the HTML.

I've tried this:
`//li[@class='footable-page-nav']/a[@class='xh-highlight']//@href`

Selenium throws an error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`

If I shorten the xpath expression to `//li[@class='footable-page-nav']` just to see if I'm on the right track then I get
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: element has zero size`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your xpath expression to

```
//li[@class='footable-page-nav']/a[contains(@class,'xh-highlight')]//@href
```

and see if it works.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='footable-page-nav']/a[contains(@class,'xh-highlight')]//@href"}

Comment: @Sol The expression works with the sample html in your question, so the sample may not be representative of the actual html.

Comment: Hmm... I got the rendered code via the chrome "View Rendered Source" extension. I built the xpath from that. But, the rendered source that Selenium sees is not identical and the piece of HTML in question is different. I'll take your word for it that your expression works and mark your answer as the accepted one.